# How to update a register in my database instead of creating a new one in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm trying to update a database register, instead I'm getting a new register, this is my update code.

```
public function edit(Producto $id){
    return view('edit', compact('id'));
}

public function update(Producto $producto, Request $request){
    $request->validate([
        'nombre' => 'required|max:100',
        'cantidad' => 'required',
        'valor_unidad' => 'required'
    ]);
    $producto->nombre = $request->nombre;
    $producto->cantidad = $request->cantidad;
    $producto->valor_unidad = $request->valor_unidad;
    $producto->valor_total = $request->valor_unidad * $request->cantidad;

    $producto->save();

    return redirect()->route('inventario.show', $producto);

}
```

}

How can I fix this? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty close! You need to make sure you are passing the ID/Primary Key in your request, then get the record before you update it:

```
public function update(Producto $producto, Request $request){
        $request->validate([
            'id'=> 'required',
            'nombre' => 'required|max:100',
            'cantidad' => 'required',
            'valor_unidad' => 'required'
        ]);
        $record = $producto::findOrFail($request->id);

        $record->nombre = $request->nombre;
        $record->cantidad = $request->cantidad;
        $record->valor_unidad = $request->valor_unidad;
        $record->valor_total = $request->valor_unidad * $request->cantidad;
    
        $record->save();
    
        return redirect()->route('inventario.show', $record);
    
    }
```

The reason why it is creating a new record instead of updating the existing one is because you did not get an instance of the record itself, but rather just accessing the model passed `update(Producto $producto, Request $request)` -- so it has no idea what record you want. You need to first query for the record (get it) and then update it.